# Market on the emulator running Google APIs 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, gmail, google-play

I was able to create an AVD running 2.2 and install the market but I would like to do the same to a AVD running 2.2 with Google APIs. When I try to install i get this:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb
>   install root/Google
>   ServicesFramework.apk 65 KB/s (728822
>   bytes in 10.916s)
>           pkg: /data/local/tmp/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
>   Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

This happens when I try to install gmail.apk and vending.apk also. It says it already exists, but I've looked and its not there.

Is it possible to install the market on the Google APIs? Or does installing GoogleServicesFramework.apk on plain 2.2 give me the same capabilities?

Comment: Please stop pirating other people's apps. The Android Market is not licensed for use on the emulator; neither is Gmail.

Comment: I'm not "pirating." this is simply to test my application. I have a link in my app that directs the user to the market (which google says to do (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)) and want to test it in the emulator as well as on my device.

Comment: You have downloaded and installed an unlicensed copy of proprietary applications in violation of their copyright, colloquially known as "piracy".